# Tree Based models vs traditional regression at identifying sub populations

Tags: random-forest, causality

Somewhat of a follow up to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436173/applying-heterogeneous-treatment-effects-to-clinical-research-non-technical-exp?noredirect=1#comment813027_436173) question I asked. Can someone provide a good non technical explanation of why tree based methods are becoming so popular for identifying sub populations of people who receive treatments (vs controls)? I've seen some mention about how trees are better with high dimensional data, but the explanations are very math heavy right now so I'm struggling with it.